# Run Python script without Windows console appearing

Tags: python, windows, shell

Is there any way to run a Python script in Windows XP without a command shell momentarily appearing? I often need to automate WordPerfect (for work) with Python, and even if my script has no output, if I execute it from without WP an empty shell still pops up for a second before disappearing. Is there any way to prevent this? Some kind of output redirection perhaps?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

pythonw.exe will run the script without a command prompt.  The problem is that the Python interpreter, Python.exe, is linked against the console subsystem to produce console output (since that's 90% of cases) -- pythonw.exe is instead linked against the GUI subsystem, and Windows will not create a console output window for it unless it asks for one.

[This article](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/python/excerpts/chpt20/index.html?page=2) discusses GUI programming with Python, and also alludes to pythonw.exe.  It also helpfully points out that if your Python files end with `.pyw` instead of `.py`, the standard Windows installer will set up associations correctly and run your Python in pythonw.exe.

In your case it doesn't sound like a problem, but reliance upon pythonw.exe makes your application Windows-specific -- other solutions exist to accomplish this on, say, Mac OS X.

Comment: Is there a way to specify inside the python script weather to use `python.exe` or `pythonw.exe`? For example, `def prog_a(): run_as_pythonw() blah blah` vs. `def prog_b(): run_as_python() blah blah`. A switch-to-silent mode, if you will.

Comment: Its not working like you explained to use pythonw.exe for .pyw. Can you please update the answer. its 2016

Comment: If your `program.pyw` still pops up a console window, it could be because you have an incorrect #! line at the beginning of the program. (Found out the hard way when copying a GUI program written for Linux — and starting with `#!/usr/bin/env python` — to Windows 7.) Just remove that line.

Answer (score 38):

If you name your files with the ".pyw" extension, then windows will execute them with the pythonw.exe interpreter. This will not open the dos console for running your script.

Comment: failed to execute script python exe

Answer (score 13):

This will work on all Windows Versions:

**1.** Create "**Runner.bat**" file with Notepad (or any other text editor) and insert following content:

```
@echo off
python server.py
```

where **server.py** is the path of the Python script you want to run.

**2.** Create "**RunScript.vbs**" file with Notepad and insert following content:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "runner.bat",0,True
```

**3.** Run the "**RunScript.vbs**" file with double click and your Python script will be runnig without any visible console windows

p.s. I know that this was not part of your question but it is often the case, if you want to run the script on windows start (after user login) just paste the shortcut of "**RunScript.vbs**" file into your startup folder. (On Windows 10 mostly under: **C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup** )

Best regards

Comment: Thanks! How to do this has been bugging me for years and years. As a mouse-hater (as well as a DOS-prompt-window-hater) I primarily wanted to be able to start using the WinKey... but if you put a shortcut of the vbs file on the desktop you can also start (without prompt) by clicking.

Comment: One thing I found by experimentation: if you put `pythonw ...` in this .bat file it causes a prompt window to flash up for a second, but if you put `python ...` you don't get that. Puzzling and counter-intuitive!

Comment: Happy to help. Most of us will never know what exactly is going on behind the scenes. Personally, I'm happy when I get the thing working as expected and doing what I want it to do. Best regards

Answer (score 10):

I tried methods above, however, a console stills appears and disappears quickly due to a Timer in my script. Finally, I found following code:

```
import ctypes
import os
import win32process

hwnd = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()      
if hwnd != 0:      
    ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(hwnd, 0)      
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(hwnd)
    _, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
    os.system('taskkill /PID ' + str(pid) + ' /f')
```

Comment: Only this one useful, other answers not working!

Answer (score 3):

Quite easy in Win10:
Open a PowerShell and type this commands:

```
type nul > openWindowed.vbs
type nul > main.py
notepad openWindowed.vbs
```

Paste the next into your *openWindowed.vbs* file:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Users\path\to\main.py" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

The *.vbs* file will execute your *main.py* file without open a cmd. I use this a lot to the *make.py* files, because I don't know cmake scripting.

Comment: I tried "type nul > openWindowed.vbs" and "nul > openWindowed.vbs".. both threw errors. It seems you're maybe just creating empty files here, right? Sorry, I know next to nothing about vbs or PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

Turn of your window defender. And install `pyinstaller` package using `pip install pyinstaller` .

After installing open cmd and type `pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole filename.py`

Answer (score 1):

Change the file extension to .pyw and add the following line (changed accordingly to your python version) to the beginning of your script:

```
#! c:\\Users\\sohra\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\pythonw.exe
```

Now, if you double click on the file, it will be executed by pythonw.exe without the console window.

Comment: The effect of this for me was to open the file in Notepad++ when I clicked on it. Also I need my Python files to work in both W10 and Linux. I assume that having this as the first line would produce an error in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The `stanza` works well via *python.exe*, whereas it fails with *pythonw.exe*. Even worse, there is no feasible mechanism to output to `sysout` or `syserr`. Therefore, I wrote the following **C#** program to start python without the Command Window:

```cs
public class Program
{
  private string python = @"D:\Libs\Python38\Python38_64\python.exe";
  private string args = "mdx_server.py";
  private string wkDir = "D:\\Program Files\\mdx-server";
    
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    Program app = new Program();
    Console.WriteLine(app.python + " " + app.args + " " + app.wkDir);
    app.Exec();
    Console.WriteLine("Start done!");
  }

  private void runThread() {
    Process process = new Process();
    try {
      process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
      process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;

      process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
      process.StartInfo.FileName = python;
      process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = wkDir;

      process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      process.Start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
  }

  public void Exec() {
    Thread _worker = new Thread(runThread);
    _worker.Start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are **2 options** in Windows, I think:

- **Option 1**

  1. Change the `.py` file extension to .`pyw` and replace `python.exe` with `pythonw.exe` at its very first line as follows (take care to replace `<your_username>\\<your_path_to>`):

     ```
     #! C:\\Users\\<your_username>\\<your_path_to>\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe
     ```
  2. Double click on `.pyw` script file to run it.
  3. Optionally, you can also create a **shortcut** to `.pyw` file, to customize its **name**, **icon** and **keyboard shortcut** as *final launcher*!
- **Option 2**

  1. Leave the `.py` file extension and replace `pythonw.exe` with `python.exe` at its very first line as follows (take care to replace `<your_username>\\<your_path_to>`):

     ```
     #! C:\\Users\\<your_username>\\<your_path_to>\\Scripts\\python.exe
     ```
  2. Use a `.vbs` (Visual Basic Script) file with the following content as launcher of the `.py` file (you can use a `.vbs` file to also launch a `.bat` file without showing the prompt):

     ```
     Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
     WshShell.Run "C:\Users\<your_username>\<your_path_to>\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\<your_username>\<your_path_to>\script.py", 0, True
     Set WshShell = Nothing
     ```
  3. Double click on `.vbs` file to run your `.py` script.
  4. Optionally, you can also create a **shortcut** to `.vbs` file, to customize its **name**, **icon** and **keyboard shortcut** as *final launcher*!

Answer (score 0):

When you install **Pyinstaller**, you will be able to convert the .py into a .exe. In the settings you can change whether to show or not show the console window that python opened when the file is ran.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I tried many options, and all of them failed
But I tried this method, and it magically worked!!!!!

So, I had this python file (mod.py) in a folder, I used to run using command prompt
When I used to close the cmd the gui is automatically closed.....(SAD),
So I run it as follows 
`C:\....>pythonw mod.py`
Don't forget `pythonw` "w" is IMP

Comment: I have .bat file which is (on Windows 10) C:\Users\XXXV\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\pythonw.exe  C:\Scripts\p1.pyw but  still the command console  shows up and remains there until the python script is finished executing

Comment: maybe if you read the answers before posting you would realize two people already provided this solution.