# Python script pops up console when run by scheduler

Tags: python, windows, windows-console, windows-task-scheduler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run python script without DOS shell appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689015/run-python-script-without-dos-shell-appearing)

I have a python script that Windows Scheduler runs every 5 minutes for me.  The script works fine but every time it runs it's loading up the console really quick on my desktop before it automatically closes.  Does anyone know how to remove this behavior?  I'd like it to just run in the background without me knowing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run it through `pythonw` instead of `python` (`pyw` if you're using the new launcher).