# Python KillProcess but hide cmd

Tags: python, python-2.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run python script without DOS shell appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689015/run-python-script-without-dos-shell-appearing)
>   [How do I hide the console when I use os.system() or subprocess.call()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006238/how-do-i-hide-the-console-when-i-use-os-system-or-subprocess-call)

I need to make a Python2.2 program to close a process. The problem is that I do not want the user to see the CMD window. Is it possible?

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /im injector* /f")
os.system("taskkill /im *injector /f")
```

Comment: related: [How do I hide the console when I use os.system() or subprocess.call()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7006238/4279)

Answer (score 0):

Try using subprocess module, samples are [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

You need to specify `shell=True`
Something like:

```
subprocess.call("taskkill.exe /im injector* /f", shell=True)
```

will not show console window.

Don't forget to

```
import subprocess
```

Comment: On Windows you almost never need `shell=True`.

Comment: In first, thanks for your answer it's much appreciated, does you know where can I find this lib ? I'm using python2.2, thanks.

Comment: @Johnsmith: `subprocess` module is in stdlib since Python 2.4. [Update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14573754/edit) to specify whether you can install Python 2.7

Comment: I can't upgrade my current version of python

Comment: Try adding this file, it says remains compatible with Python 2.2 http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/subprocess.py

Comment: So I've added it:
import subprocess
subprocess.call("taskkill.exe /im injector* /f", shell=True)
I've got this error: ImportError:No module named subprocess

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm a little tired.. thanks.

Comment: so it worked or new error?

Comment: I've got an other error: SyntaxError:invalid syntax (line 470)

Comment: 470 of subprocess.py or your own code? 470 of subprocess is try: line

Comment: I've needed to import threading then maybe can be threading or subprocess, my own code is of 80 line

Comment: no idea, I don't have python 2.2 to test, your question is so specific, python 2.2 (not upgradable) and you want to hide console window and use subprocess module which is introduced in python 2.4

Comment: I know, I'm really blocked with it, there is nothing other alternativ ?

Comment: AFAIK no, subprocess is the way to go.

Comment: I've been upgrade to python 2.7, the 470 line error stay, she comes from threading, thanks.

Comment: if you have python 2.7 you don't need that subprocess.py to be in your folder, remove it. Python 2.7 already have that code

Comment: I've removed it doesn't change nothing, the error about subprocess is not defined.. I gotty crazy

Comment: verify you are running correct python version with python --version

Comment: Ok so, my last problem is about the threading, does I really need it ?

Comment: I think so, so it finally worked?

Comment: No coz "No module named threading" but if I import it, I gotta the error say before...

Comment: you verified python version? that code simply works in my Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: I've see, I've wrong file, then I've not really updated the correct files, I've retry to upgrade and doesn't work more with 2.7...

Comment: You are missing a point, re-check everything, in python 2.7 everything should work well.

Comment: Just an other ask, does it's possible with python22 to check if a process is started ?

Comment: you can ask another question, simply accept an answer, close this question, start a new question and ask it there