# How to Hide the Default Python Shell when using a UI

Tags: python, shell, user-interface, tkinter

I am using a Tkinter UI in my Python program, but the default shell, command prompt-like, shell app is still there in the background.

I am using Python 3.4 with the Tkinter UI, as stated earlier.

Is there any way to hide or remove the shell, stopping it from opening behind the UI. I don't want something that just minimises it to the taskbar, but something that actually hides or removes it.

If you need any details, leave a comment below and I'll update the question with the details required in it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

PS: While I prefer as little lines as possible, I'm not really bothered. If you have something that is multi-line, just use that, don't try and compact it into one line, thanks. :)

**PC Details**

Although I would prefer this to work with any OS, my OS is Windows 8.1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689015/run-python-script-without-dos-shell-appearing ?

Comment: -Eric Levieil,

Thanks for the Support, it really helped me :D

Comment: BTW, the window you see from `python` is not a shell, it is called a *console window*.