# Run python GUI packaged to win32 without console

Tags: python, user-interface

Please i really need help.

I have this problem which i have been unable to solve.

I wrote some python gui script of which i want to create a win32 app from for portabilty(i.e not compel all my app user to download/install python) and to make my application close sourced.

I have decided to use/ tried using pyinstaller and py2exe but have always had this problem. My gui application shows up with a console window accompanining it.

I have tried several thing to prevent this but all were in vain. I tried changing the extension from .py to .pyw and repackaging but got same result.

Please i need help on how to avoid/override this. Thanks for you help in advance

Note: I use python 2.7.11 on a window 7 32bit system.
And please dont mark my question as duplicate in reference to questions like : [Run Python script without Windows console appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689015/run-python-script-without-dos-shell-appearing) or [How to hide console window in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python) as my question is completely different.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `pyinstaller.py  --onefile --no-console my_script.py`

Comment: What i mean exactly is: for example most java programmer or any body who have used or seen netbeans at startup might notice the fact that at first netbeans displays a console window which latter vanished after some second following the appearance of a splash scren.
Unlike the other java ide "bluej" which shows a console window which persists throughout the use of the program.

So i mean that i need something similar to that of netbeans.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks joran. I think that should work/ is what i need but i am yet to confirm it. I will tomorrow and will get back to you then because it is already midnight here in Nigeria.


For sschale, no need for code here i guess because i/one just need to follow the normal syntax of packaging with py2exe or pyinstaller

Thanks

Comment: Thanks joran it worked though not exactly as you stated.

Comment: Please is there also anyother way to do it using py2exe

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working with pyinstaller by using the --no-console argument i.e by adding -w. Here is the syntax of my code.

```
pyinstaller -F -w my_script.py
```

where -F is to creates one file for standalone app i.e --onefile and -w is to disable console window i.e --no-console.

Thanks.