# Python 3 - Desactivate the display of the console

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I have a GUI program on python 3 and a `file.txt` which contains some launch options. One of them is :

```
Console (Yes/No) = ...
```

The thing is i want to display or not the console if there is a "Yes" or a "No".

I found a way to do so :

In `script1.pyw`:

```
import os

def getParam():
    param = open("file.txt","r").read()
    param.split(" = ")[1] # getting the value of "Console = "

    return(param)

param = getParam()

if "script2.py" in listdir():

    if param == "No":
        os.rename("script2.py","script2.pyw")
        os.system("python script2.pyw")

    elif param == "Yes":
        os.system("python script2.py")

if "script2.py" in listdir():

    if param == "Yes":
        os.rename("script2.pyw","script2.py")
        os.system("python script2.py")

    elif param == "No":
        os.system("python script2.pyw")
```

In `script2.py(w)`:

```
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()

...

window.mainloop()
```

Fortunately it works but as I work on Linux and I want to share my program with people on Windows I encountered a problem : when they launch `script1.pyw` everything goes well but whatever they put in `file.txt`, the python's shell opens with it (and it is absolutely not what I want...)

Do someone have any idea?

Comment: FYI you don't need to come up with your own format for configuration: https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Python script without Windows console appearing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689015/run-python-script-without-windows-console-appearing)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the **os.system** call to **subprocess.call** in order to skip the black window, maybe something like this:

```
subprocess.call(['py', '3.4', '-c', "import time; time.sleep(1)"], shell=True)
```

The *shell=True* part is what keeps the console from showing...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `pythow.exe` on Windows:

```
pythonw script2.pyw
```

Better don't use `os.sytem`. It is recommend to use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess):

```
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    subprocess.call(['pythonw',  'script2.pyw'], shell=True)
```

The [`os.sytem` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) recommend `subprocess`:

> The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function.

Comment: It's best to avoid using `shell=True`. In this case it's completely unnecessary because pythonw.exe is not a console application. However, even if the target is a console app, such as python.exe, using `shell=True` just to get a hidden console is generally a bad idea. The better options are either to set the `startupinfo` yourself to hide the console window or to use a `creationflags` value of either `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` or `DETACHED_PROCESS`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7006424/205580) for examples.