# Make VBA wait until batch file is finished

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-access, batch-file

I am using VBA in my Access DB to launch a batch file which is linked to PS1 script.

That all works as intended. The issue is that I want to run some queries after that action is completed, but as it stands I need to babysit the whole thing. So I am looking for a solution to keep the VBA paused while the batch is running.

I found this article: https://danwagner.co/how-to-run-a-batch-file-and-wait-until-it-finishes-with-vba/

But the solution doesn't work for me for some reason. The batch runs, but the VBA just steams on ahead without pausing.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button_UpdateOffline_Click()

Dim strCommand As String
Dim lngErrorCode As Long
Dim wsh As WshShell
Set wsh = New WshShell

DoCmd.OpenForm "Please_Wait"

'Run the batch file using the WshShell object
strCommand = Chr(34) & _
             "C:\Users\Rip\Q_Update.bat" & _
             Chr(34)
lngErrorCode = wsh.Run(strCommand, _
                       WindowStyle:=0, _
                       WaitOnReturn:=True)
If lngErrorCode <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Uh oh! Something went wrong with the batch file!"
    Exit Sub
End If

DoCmd.Close acForm, "Please_Wait"

End Sub
```

Here is my batch code if that helps:

```
START PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'C:\Users\Rip\PS1\OfflineFAQ_Update.ps1' "
```

Comment: Review https://www.devhut.net/vba-wmi-determine-if-a-process-is-running-or-not/

Comment: Simple method: Create a file in VBA, start the batch, have VBA wait while the file exists, batch deletes the file as a final step, VBA continues...

Comment: You should use `-File` to run a PowerShell script, not `-Command`. Example ```@Start "PS1" %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\Users\Rip\PS1\OfflineFAQ_Update.ps1"```.

Comment: Magoo! That is brilliant and easy! 

I didn't actually do what you suggested here, but it got me to the solution. 

The PS1 file is updated an excel file, so I have my code look for the excel lock file! Once the lock file is gone, the code marches on!

Comment: @Compo, thanks for the code update! I'm not sure what the difference is, but it's running smoothly, so that's the important thing for me! 

Do you happen to know if I can add something to the code to stop the window from popping up? Basically running the code in the background?

Comment: For that @Lowendz113, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1689015).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your batch code launches PowerShell, then closes.

VBA waits until your batch code has launched PowerShell, then continues. It has no way to know you actually want to wait until *PowerShell* has finished, since if you want to wait on that, you'd have to make your batch script wait as well.

So, either change the batch code to include `/WAIT`, in addition to the changes suggested in the comments:

```
START /wait PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'C:\Users\Rip\PS1\OfflineFAQ_Update.ps1' "
```

Or, open PowerShell directly without the batch file in between:

```
strCommand = "PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ""& 'C:\Users\Rip\PS1\OfflineFAQ_Update.ps1' """
```

Comment: Well holy crap. That was easy! Cheers mate!

Comment: I went with the /wait method as that was the easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *WaitForSingleObject* API call. It takes a bit lengthy code, but is very simple to implement when wrapped in a function like `ShellWait` below.

This way, you can call the PowerShell command directly as in this example:

```vb
' Unblock a file or all files of a folder.
'
' 2022-10-18. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function UnblockFiles( _
    ByVal Path As String) _
    As Boolean

    Const CommandMask   As String = "PowerShell -command {0}"
    Const ArgumentMask  As String = "Dir ""{0}"" -Recurse | Unblock-File"
    Const WindowStyle   As Long = VbAppWinStyle.vbHide
    
    Dim Argument        As String
    Dim Command         As String
    Dim Result          As Long
    Dim Success         As Boolean
    
    If Dir(Path, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        ' Path is neither a file nor a folder.
    Else
        ' Continue.
        Argument = Replace(ArgumentMask, "{0}", Path)
        Command = Replace(CommandMask, "{0}", Argument)
        Result = ShellWait(Command, WindowStyle)
        Success = Not CBool(Result)
    End If
    
    UnblockFiles = Success
    
End Function
```

You'll see, that the `command` is assembled from the top two constants and a variable. You should be able to modify those for your command.

The `ShellWait` I use:

```vb
' General constants.
'
' Wait forever.
Private Const Infinite              As Long = &HFFFF

' Process Security and Access Rights.
'
' The right to use the object for synchronization.
' This enables a thread to wait until the object is in the signaled state.
Private Const Synchronize           As Long = &H100000

' Constants for WaitForSingleObject.
'
' The specified object is a mutex object that was not released by the thread
' that owned the mutex object before the owning thread terminated.
' Ownership of the mutex object is granted to the calling thread and the
' mutex state is set to nonsignaled.
Private Const StatusAbandonedWait0  As Long = &H80
Private Const WaitAbandoned         As Long = StatusAbandonedWait0 + 0
' The state of the specified object is signaled.
Private Const StatusWait0           As Long = &H0
Private Const WaitObject0           As Long = StatusWait0 + 0
' The time-out interval elapsed, and the object's state is nonsignaled.
Private Const WaitTimeout           As Long = &H102
' The function has failed. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.
Private Const WaitFailed            As Long = &HFFFFFFFF


' Missing enum when using late binding.
'
#If EarlyBinding = False Then
    Public Enum IOMode
        ForAppending = 8
        ForReading = 1
        ForWriting = 2
    End Enum
#End If


' API declarations.

' Opens an existing local process object.
' If the function succeeds, the return value is an open handle
' to the specified process.
' If the function fails, the return value is NULL (0).
' To get extended error information, call GetLastError.
'
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" ( _
        ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
        ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
        ByVal dwProcessId As Long) _
        As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" ( _
        ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
        ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
        ByVal dwProcessId As Long) _
        As Long
#End If

' The WaitForSingleObject function returns when one of the following occurs:
' - the specified object is in the signaled state.
' - the time-out interval elapses.
'
' The dwMilliseconds parameter specifies the time-out interval, in milliseconds.
' The function returns if the interval elapses, even if the object's state is
' nonsignaled.
' If dwMilliseconds is zero, the function tests the object's state and returns
' immediately.
' If dwMilliseconds is Infinite, the function's time-out interval never elapses.
'
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" ( _
        ByVal hHandle As LongPtr, _
        ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) _
        As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" ( _
        ByVal hHandle As Long, _
        ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) _
        As Long
#End If

' Closes an open object handle.
' If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
' If the function fails, the return value is zero.
' To get extended error information, call GetLastError.
'
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" ( _
        ByVal hObject As LongPtr) _
        As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" ( _
        ByVal hObject As Long) _
        As Long
#End If


' Shells out to an external process and waits until the process ends.
' Returns 0 (zero) for no errors, or an error code.
'
' The call will wait for an infinite amount of time for the process to end.
' The process will seem frozen until the shelled process terminates. Thus,
' if the shelled process hangs, so will this.
'
' A better approach could be to wait a specific amount of time and, when the
' time-out interval expires, test the return value. If it is WaitTimeout, the
' process is still not signaled. Then either wait again or continue with the
' processing.
'
' Waiting for a DOS application is different, as the DOS window doesn't close
' when the application is done.
' To avoid this, prefix the application command called (shelled to) with:
' "command.com /c " or "cmd.exe /c ".
'
' For example:
'   Command = "cmd.exe /c " & Command
'   Result = ShellWait(Command)
'
' 2018-04-06. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function ShellWait( _
    ByVal Command As String, _
    Optional ByVal WindowStyle As VbAppWinStyle = vbNormalNoFocus) _
    As Long

    Const InheritHandle As Long = &H0
    Const NoProcess     As Long = 0
    Const NoHandle      As Long = 0
    
#If VBA7 Then
    Dim ProcessHandle   As LongPtr
#Else
    Dim ProcessHandle   As Long
#End If
    Dim DesiredAccess   As Long
    Dim ProcessId       As Long
    Dim WaitTime        As Long
    Dim Closed          As Boolean
    Dim Result          As Long
  
    If Len(Trim(Command)) = 0 Then
        ' Nothing to do. Exit.
    Else
        ProcessId = Shell(Command, WindowStyle)
        If ProcessId = NoProcess Then
            ' Process could not be started.
        Else
            ' Get a handle to the shelled process.
            DesiredAccess = Synchronize
            ProcessHandle = OpenProcess(DesiredAccess, InheritHandle, ProcessId)
            ' Wait "forever".
            WaitTime = Infinite
            ' If successful, wait for the application to end and close the handle.
            If ProcessHandle = NoHandle Then
                ' Should not happen.
            Else
                ' Process is running.
                Result = WaitForSingleObject(ProcessHandle, WaitTime)
                ' Process ended.
                Select Case Result
                    Case WaitObject0
                        ' Success.
                    Case WaitAbandoned, WaitTimeout, WaitFailed
                        ' Know error.
                    Case Else
                        ' Other error.
                End Select
                ' Close process.
                Closed = CBool(CloseHandle(ProcessHandle))
                If Result = WaitObject0 Then
                    ' Return error if not closed.
                    Result = Not Closed
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
  
    ShellWait = Result

End Function
```