# How to use the win32gui module with Python?

Tags: python, win32gui, activestate

Im my Python file, I have imported the `win32gui` module like this:

```
import win32gui
```

I have also downloaded `win32gui` but don't know how to make my script run. How can I run my Python script which imports `win32gui`? When I run it, I get:

```
ImportError: No module named win32gui
```

Sorry for the newbie question but I'm trying to learn Python so don't know much about it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When on a windows platform, I usually go for the executables. They should work all the time. Try perhaps one of the files listed here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build216/

It's the most recent build. Choose the one appropriate to your Python's version.

Comment: To complement this helpful answer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/ is version-independent and shows more detailed instructions.

Answer (score 2):

this is a module from Marc Hammond's well-known pywin32 extension module, you can also get the source and compile it quite easily (I found I needed to do this because I needed a 64 bit build and couldn't find one at the time).  The mercurial address to get it is:

http://pywin32.hg.sourceforge.net:8000/hgroot/pywin32/pywin32

there are visual studio project files in the .\pywin32\win32 directory...