# Install win32gui module. error

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, win32gui

I need to use win32gui in my python project. I have a clean Windows 8.1 installation. I Installed "python-3.4.2.amd64" and "pywin32-219.win-amd64-py3.4" and both installation went smooth with no errors but when I try to run a script, it just give me error in the import phase:

ImportError: No module named win32gui

any help?

Comment: this is the report from the pywin32 installation:
Copied pythoncom34.dll to C:\windows\system32\pythoncom34.dll
Copied pywintypes34.dll to C:\windows\system32\pywintypes34.dll
Registered: Python.Interpreter
Registered: Python.Dictionary 
Registered: Python 
-> Software\Python\PythonCore\3.4\Help[None]=None
-> Software\Python\PythonCore\3.4\Help\Pythonwin Reference[None]='C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyWin32.chm'
Pythonwin has been registered in context menu
Shortcut for Pythonwin created
Shortcut to documentation created
The pywin32 extensions were successfully installed.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624672/how-to-use-the-win32gui-module-with-python ?