# Hide console from Python script?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide console window in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python)

I have a simple script with one messagedialog only...

how can I hide the console from it when I execute the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute the script using `pythonw.exe` rather than `python.exe`. You can set that up to happen automatically by giving the script the extension `.pyw` rather than `.py`.

Comment: but I will transform this script in executable... how do I do then?

Comment: @Shady: Define "transform", and elaborate on how you're using the script in your executable.

Comment: That sort of depends on how you turn it into an executable.  If you are using py2exe then it is an option inside your configuration file.

Comment: @JAB, sorry for the lack of info, p2exe, and I've managed to work, thanks for the help