# Windows - Popen with wShowWindow in startupinfo not affecting display

Tags: python, windows, popen, subprocess, win32gui

I'm trying to do something simple like get calc.exe to start minimized, but it's not happening.

```
import subprocess
import win32gui
import win32con

info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = win32con.SW_SHOWMINIMIZED
x = subprocess.Popen("calc.exe", startupinfo = info)
```

It pops up the same as always, no matter what I provide for `wShowWindow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've already figured this out, but for the benefit of other readers here's my take:

The problem has something to do specifically with the `calc.exe` program, not Python nor your code. To prove it, try launching "notepad.exe" (or "wordpad.exe") and it will work -- also note you may need to supply the full path to the target `.exe` file depending on where it is.

Specifically what is wrong, is according to the `STARTUPINFO` structure, the `wShowWindow` member:

> For GUI processes, the first time ShowWindow is called, its nCmdShow parameter is ignored wShowWindow specifies the default value. In subsequent calls to ShowWindow, the wShowWindow member is used if the nCmdShow parameter of ShowWindow is set to SW_SHOWDEFAULT.

So what this means is, the first time a program starts, and calls `ShowWindow()`, it completely ignores whatever you have passed in for `wShowWindow` in the `STARTUPINFO` structure. Then, upon another call to `ShowWindow()`, it will **only** use your provided value for wShowWindow if the program calls `ShowWindow()` with its `nCmdShow` parameter set to `SW_SHOWDEFAULT`.

So, it seems to be impossible to hide a GUI window if the program itself provides its own value for `nCmdShow` in `ShowWindow()`, so it just seems like trial and error to see which programs do that, such as notepad.exe allows you to hide it, while calc.exe you cannot.

Comment: Right you are. Calc just doesn't accept startupinfo it seems.