# Windows batch script START /B not working

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, command-line

I have created a batch script in order to start a custom Python script that I am running on Windows. However, what I could like to do is not have the command line window appear.

I did some research and I found that if I used the prefix START /B, the command line window will now appear.

```
cd %~dp0
START /B .\Modules\monitor.pyw
```

However, this method does not appear to work when I explicitly specify the Python executable like so:

```
cd %~dp0
START /B .\Python27\python .\Modules\monitor.pyw
```

The question is, why does the line above not work in the same way as the line with the explicit executable path? Thanks!

Comment: `cmd.exe` does not open a new console window for the application started with `start /B`. But a console window is opened for the execution of the batch file containing those 2 lines. And if Python itself creates a console window, the usage of option `/B` does not prevent creation of a console window. Check the documentation for [command line options of Python](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html) if there is an option to avoid opening a console window. BTW: Better use `cd /D "%~dp0"` as first line.

Comment: Note that I have set the extension of my python script to .pyw in order to prevent the console window from opening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide console window in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have Python installed. But I suppose that a switch is needed on starting `python.exe` in Windows GUI mode or a different application.

I suggest to look which command is configured in Windows registry for opening a *.pyw file.

According to reply by ghostdog74 on [What is the difference between .py and .pyw?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=338601) I'm right with my assumption.

*.pyw must be interpreted with `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe` to run the Python script in Windows GUI mode instead of console mode.

So you have to change the command line by inserting character `w`.