# how to remove black terminal while running my my executable file in tkinter for python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I Have made small program from tkinter python. while i run this executable program i see black screen in background. i have attached images in this link 
(https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B77Z7Ug9rVFFfmlpMXRfbTlUR1ZuQjVNbV9VWmMtZUk2amhrMHYxRWprSnJGdGh1TVdNbVU&usp=sharing)

I want to remove this black screen because i want to pack this program to .exe format without this black screen.

Waiting for proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should save your script with `.pyw` extension.

Comment: Why? What's the difference? Can you explain?

Comment: @ ForceBru because with pyw windows execute script with pythonw.exe. this program is written specially for windows.