# How to make the text shell not appear when running a program

Tags: python, pygame, python-idle

I'm just wondering (as im starting to make a game with pygame) is there a way to 1) Run a program that only opens a GUI and not the shell
and 
2) Run the program without having to edit with idle (I'd like to do this so the game will look more professional.

I would like to just have a desktop shortcut or something that when clicked, runs only the GUI and doesnt show my code or show the shell.

Comment: Is such behaviour not operating system dependent? What are you using?

Comment: related: [How to hide console window in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/764631/4279)

Comment: Developing a pygame game with Idle is fine (worked great for my child), but once developed, run it directly with python or, on Windows, pythonw.exe, as Dval said.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on windows, a quick thing could be to make a one-line batch script.

`start pythonw.exe <filename>`

The start keyword causes the shell to not wait for the program to finish. 
pythonw vs python prevents the python terminal from appearing.

If you're on linux/mac, you could do the same with shell scripts.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry im not a high enough level to upvote but thanks anyway!

Comment: @finlx: if you use `.pyw` file extension for your Python script then double-clicking on it should use `pythonw.exe` automatically. You can always specify the necessary command in a desktop shortcut; no need to create a bat-file (google "create desktop shortcut").

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks as well! Just wondering, if i use this method will it open in cmd or will it open in idle?

Comment: @finlx: neither. It runs `pythonw.exe` directly (that runs your script.py)