# How to properly close Python exe console program

Tags: python, executable, exit, py2exe

I'm trying to figure out how to do exit if the program is done with it's work. 
What should I use?

I've tried:

```
sys.exit()
```

and

```
os._exit(0)
```

But none of them worked in `exe` created by `Py2Exe`. It works when it is runned as a `py` script but if I create an `exe`, those `exit` commands do nothing.

Comment: Define "do nothing". So if you compile `print("a"); sys.exit(); print("b")` into an executable and run it, it will print both "a" and "b"?

Comment: It prints 'a'. There is no 'b' ... I'm on windows.

Comment: In that case, `sys.exit` is working as intended. It makes the program stop running before "b" gets printed. Can you explain further exactly what else you expect it to do?

Comment: I want to close the console window. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: Maybe [How to hide console window in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/764631/953482) will be useful to you, then.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik did you ever find a solution? am running into the same problem. Pls share whatever worked for you, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use: *quit()* 
In python's command prompt

Answer (score 2):

Use pyinstaller instead of py2exe you will love it :). `sys.exit()` should work on pyinstaller.

to install

```
python -m pip install pyinstaller
```

to build exe in single file

```
pyinstaller yourscript.py --onefile
```

to build a gui app w/o console

```
pyinstaller yourscript.py --noconsole
```

If you have problem using pyinstaller dont hesitate to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using a console window, it will automatically close at the end of your program.

`print("Hello World")
 input()`

If you run the .py file, a terminal window should pop up that says hello world. When you hit enter(the input part) the program will look for another line of code and when it finds none, will close the program and console window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to execute a command from cmd on python just add \c to the command, and it will close after its execution

example os.system(r'cmd /c "C:\Program Files\PATH" -file C:\PATH.exe')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).