# pyqt gui console keeps opening

Tags: python, pyinstaller, spyder

so i am running python 3.5 and spyder 3.2.8 and pyinstaller
i have made a gui with designer used the main thats shows below.

```
def run():
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

my question is about that  when i use the pyinstaller to make the exe i run it and a console pop ups along with the gui and when i close it, all the gui closes. any idea?

Comment: Is your indentation in your program as shown here?

Comment: no just copied it like that the program works as it should but my problem is that a console is open too and i want only the gui to show.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide console window in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python)

Comment: @KarstenKoop according to the answer (@iMBLISH please accept the answer) to use an argument, it doesn't seem as a duplicate. Voting to leave open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use '--noconsole' argument while creating your .exe using pyinstaller

refer documentation for more details:-http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to indent it properly to have your code only execute when run() is invoked.

```
def run():
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Comment: remove your answer before someone starts downvoting... the code will not run without indentation

Comment: copied it wrong i have it like that the gui shows and works but a console is also open and i want only the gui to show.