# Hide Command Window using Python

Tags: python

I use os.system () to run a batch file in command prompt, but command prompt also displays when the batch file is running. Is there any way to hide the command prompt?

Comment: Are you asking about running the batch file in background ?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python