# Open console only for input and close it afterwards

Tags: python

I am trying to build my own Voice Assistant and I dont want to see any console window when I am using it.
To do that I created this batch file:

```
@echo off
C:\Users\koeje\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\pythonw.exe 
C:\Users\koeje\Documents\Python\VoiceAssistant\main.py %*
pause
```

Because there is still a console window opening I created a vbs file witch gets opend by autostart:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Users\koeje\Documents\Python\VoiceAssistant\VoiceAssistant.bat" & Chr(34),0 
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Now its working fine and I cant see any console window.
My only problem now is that I use the spotipy package and that I have to manually insert a url which the package is opening in my browser.

```
token  = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id = client_id, client_secret = client_secret, redirect_uri = redirect_uri)
```

The package runs this code and then I have to insert the URL.

Is there any way that python can open the consol, accept my url and closes the console afterwards?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49284765/10039400) do what you want?

Comment: @DJSchaffner Yes this worked thank you!