# .py script converted to .exe still shows console when run with admin privileges

Tags: python, windows, console, exe, pyinstaller

I made a super simple program that only closes the windows magnifier program.

```
    import os
    os.system ("taskkill /f /im Magnify.exe")
```

I made it so I could assign it to a macro on my keyboard with corsair icue. After giving the .exe admin privileges and disabling UAC, it works with one button press. The problem is the console window pops up when it runs and it takes focus away from the game window.

I used pyinstaller to convert the .py file and tried -w, and --noconsole. Despite this the console still shows up for a split second and takes focus off the game.

Is a way to make the program run without showing the console and taking away focus?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python, have you specifically tried the `.pyw` extension?

Comment: Yeah I did, it still flashed on screen for a split second.