# Is there a way to ping without showing the command window output of it?

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, ping

I have this code to check ping to a server :

`PingServer = subprocess.call('ping /n 2 /w 1000 ' + SERVER_IP +'')`

When converted to EXE, this line outputs to the end user the command window with ping results which closes after 2 seconds.

Is there a way to hide it?

Comment: maybe use `subprocess.get_output()` the same way, also for the exe convert it to noconsole

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/764631/15740324)

Comment: Executing external programs is rarely a good solution, if you can avoid it. And you can avoid it - use a package such as [pythonping](https://pypi.org/project/pythonping/) or [python-ping](https://pypi.org/project/python-ping/). Or you could roll your own ICMP utility code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a serious answer to your question
"this line outputs to the end user the command window with ping results which closes after 2 seconds. Is there a way to hide it?"

Yes there is,
however a call to cmd is a call to run a console, thus a console by definition must be accessible and generally visible to the console user.

So the Option is given to minimise the in your face black screen, its a shame that the old ansi waiting... screen art died out with faster computers.

So replace your

```
PingServer = subprocess.call('ping /n 2 /w 1000 ' + SERVER_IP +'')
```

with something like

```
PingServer = subprocess.call('start "PingingServer" /min ping /n 2 /w 1000 ' + SERVER_IP +'', shell=True)
```

NOTE:- I have not tested how that would work in different applications "Calling" methods so the " quotes may need escaping in different ways

such as `start \"PingingServer\" /min ...` or `start '+ TITLE_MSG +' /min ...`

And a user would only see the brief notification hidden in the taskbar.
**Here ignore the background** console that's me testing out this answer, I have intentionally expanded the task bar icon, to show the worst a user would see is that icon, and by the time they tried clicking the 2 second self destruct would have kicked in.

[image]

Comment: Thank you - this looks like a great solution. Tried it manually in Windows CMD and it works great. But inside my code it is not working. Can you tell me what I`m missing here ?

Comment: It now tells me : FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified. Is this because i removed the name of the window..?

Comment: It looks like it`s searching the START file. Maybe need slashes modifications?