# How to keep python debug consol from opening when I run code in vsdode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Whenever I run code by pressing Ctrl + F5 vscode will automatically swap to the python debug console is there a way that I can stop this?

Comment: That's exactly what ctrl-F5 does; it runs your script using just the regular Python executable, which will open a console unless you do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python). What are you expecting/wanting to happen? Where should the script output go?

Comment: i explained my problem badly what happens is it will swap off of the debug console or regular cmd and open a terminal called python debug console

Comment: I am afraid it's impossible. And it's a good classify of consoles.